# Change checkMark or size of CheckedTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, checkedtextview

I'm working on an application where I'm using a checkedTextView, it all works great. But I really don't like that layout of the "checkbox" within the checkedTextView, it's simply to big. Is there any way to resize it or change the layout to something custom made?

I've tried the `android:checkMark` attribute, but that resulted in it being marked all the time, and thus showing all the time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of using a single drawable you should write a selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_checked"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_unchecked"
        android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

And then set it to the `android:checkMark` attribute.

Comment: This didnt work for me, the check mark still doesnt change :/

Comment: @Siavash, you most likely need to implement the onClickListener for the CheckedTextView, to run `((CheckedTextView)view).toggle();`

Comment: it works for me!but ,if if it was not checked ,i set checkmark null,how do i set it

Comment: Works well, I just set it to `android:drawableLeft` with `android:checkMark="@null"` as I wanted to have the checkbox on the left.