# How to move the check mark place of android CheckedTextView?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, checkedtextview

I am trying to create a list of `CheckedTextView` as shown below in the image:
[image]

What I did so far is to create a `LinearLayout` and add 5 `CheckedTextView`. But I need the check mark to be customized. I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954100/change-checkmark-or-size-of-checkedtextview), but this doesn't move the check mark place as it's in the image.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <CheckedTextView 
       android:textColor="#c0c0c0"
       android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp" 
       android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
       android:textSize="18sp" 
       android:text="@string/first_tone"
       android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
       android:paddingRight="15dip"
       android:background="@drawable/border"
       android:gravity="center_vertical" />
   
   <CheckedTextView 
       android:textColor="#c0c0c0"
       android:id="@+id/checkedTextView2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp" 
       android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       android:text="@string/second_tone" 
       android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
       android:paddingRight="15dip"
       android:gravity="center_vertical" />
   
   <CheckedTextView 
       android:textColor="#c0c0c0"
       android:id="@+id/checkedTextView3" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp" 
       android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
       android:textSize="18sp" 
       android:text="@string/third_tone"
       android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
       android:paddingRight="15dip"
       android:gravity="center_vertical" />
   
   <CheckedTextView 
       android:textColor="#c0c0c0"
       android:id="@+id/checkedTextView4"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp" 
       android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
       android:textSize="18sp" 
       android:text="@string/fourth_tone"
       android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
       android:paddingRight="15dip"
       android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me how to place the check mark at the middle of the green border?

Thanks :)

Comment: use InsetDrawable as a checkMark

Comment: Ya accroding to @pskink use InsetDrawable as a checkMark.......